# .net client ssl connect to wephsere mq

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

Hi I want to connect webpshere mq .net client.And I dont want to use any environmet variable set in to server or my client pc.

I check but I cant,I also set path and chipper in connection properties but I failed.Can some share .net code sample with ssl connection

```
 connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, SSLPath);
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, SSLChipper);

          MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384";
            MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = SSLPath;// path is my cer and tab files folder
            MQEnvironment.properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, ConnectionType);
            MQEnvironment.ConnectionName = HostName;
            MQEnvironment.Channel = channelName;


            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, connectionProperties);
```

I found this topic but they suggest setting environment variable directly
[.NET client connecting to IBM MQ over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663231/net-client-connecting-to-ibm-mq-over-ssl)

@Update only want to use amqdmdnet(8.0.0.7) My Final code like that I dont want to set enviroment variable.

string ConnectionName = string.Format("{0}({1})", HostName, Port);

```
 Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
 connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Port);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, ConnectionName);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);


connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, @"D:\D\MYcertificates\Client\client_4_certificate"); //without .kdb but folder path
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);

connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY,"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCMSHA384");

            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, connectionProperties);
```

For these code I got 2538 error.

@Update3

I change my cert_store property and upload to certificate my windows store connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*USER");
that time I pass 2538 error and take 2059 error.In error detail I got this error what ever I send chipperspec property it is not send to server correctly

In my code I sent
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA");

I got error
The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is
'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA'. The name of the CipherSpec negotiated during
the SSL handshake is 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'. A code is displayed if the
name of the negotiated CipherSpec cannot be determined.

Comment: What is ConnectionType set to?

Comment: I tried two type MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED; but not working,and  MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT if I set this this time IBM.WMQ initialize error with these parameters.Also I not give connection type and it is also not working

Comment: I dont have mq client my pc for that reason I try to use  MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED;If you have code sample please share for  TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED

Comment: What version of MQ is your amqmdnet.dll from?

Comment: 8.0.0.7 ,managed client    properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, SslKeyRepository);              properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, CipherSpec);roperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, MQHostname);
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, MQ,PortNumber);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, MqChannel);            
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED); I got 2538 error but normal unssl channel I can access these port and queuemanager

Comment: Is this different than what you posted in your question?   If you need to post code,  click edit and add it to your question.

Comment: not different same question ,I just send my properties info .TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED I got 2538 error

Comment: See this answer for more help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347768/ibm-mq-net-certificatelabel-cipherspec/42348037#42348037.

Comment: If that answer does not solve your problem then please explain your setup more.  You need to use the Windows certificate store.  The label needs to be what MQ is expecting, and the SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY is ignored except to denote if SSL or TLS should be used, the cipherspec is specified in the Windows Group Policy.

Comment: connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, SSLChipper); when I set chipperspec property like "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"; I got 2538 error and not access the queue but when I comment this line that time I got 2059 error.When I check ibm spec table spec value is valid but I am not finding the reason.Can you share a sample to access ssl queue manager with TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED,thank you @JoshMc

Comment: Did you review the Q/A that I linked to above?  Have you reviewed the errors produced on the queue manager error logs when you get 2538 vs 2059?

Comment: Note that if you only want to reference the `amqmdnet.dll` then you must run in managed mode.  The question I references is related to this specific topic.  Note that you would not reference `MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository` in Managed mode.  Also I suggest that you click "edit" under your question and provide example code that does not include variables or at least shows what those variables are set to.  Also provide the full errors received.  You can even state when you try X you get Y response, etc.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc yes I want to use only amqmdnet.dll and managed mode,I changes my code and update my question above but I still error may be you find my missing point .

Comment: Please read the Question and Answer I linked to above.  With Managed mode you do not have a key store (kdb) you use the windows cert store.  It also explains that while you need to specify a cipherspec it is only used in Managed mode to specify TLS or SSL not a specific cipherspec.  Please read it and try to fix your problem.  If you still have issues please post the exact error you receive along with what shows on the queue manager's logs.

Comment: @JoshMc ,your post very helpful and I update my question (update3),do you have any idea to not setting chipperspec property correctly thanks,For the IBM MQ.NET managed client, the SSL settings are for the Microsoft.NET SSLStream class. For SSLStream, a CipherSpec, or a preference list of CipherSpecs, can be set only in the Windows group policy, which is a computer-wide setting,is there any way to pass group policy

Comment: Look at this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364718/2538-error-on-mq-for-ssl-channel-connection/46418392#46418392

Comment: Hi I try to change default chipper spec in regedit under localmachine\cryptography\configuration\local\ssl\001002\ functions property but it is not work which regedit configuration should I change?to set default chipper spec